# Apache rewrite not working for Zope - yet again

Tags: python, apache, mod-rewrite, zope

I know this has been covered before and I've spent hours on this site and others trying to be sure I am doing everything correctly, but the bottom line is the rewrite isn't working - I keep on seeing the Apache default page and not the Zope page, and I am not getting any errors (I have trace5 on)

Here's the background: I finally had to move an ancient  instance of Zope (2.4.4 w/Python 2.1) off an ancient server-the last move was in 2005! I actually managed to get Zope running on a 32 bit 16.04 VM using Azure's new nested Hyper-V - but that's another story :)

I basically copied everything over from the old server to the new one (including Python 2.1, Zope 2.4.4 and the Zope instance) to get this working, along with the Apache configuration files. The only thing new besides Ubuntu 16.04 (I had dapper on the old machine - no evil comments please :)) was Apache.

I've checked that I have `rewrite`, `proxy` and `proxy_http` mods enabled. In the `proxy.conf` I have `proxyposts on` and `allowed from localhost`. In the `enabled-sites` conf file for the document root `/` and `/var/www/html` I `AllowOverride All` and `Require all granted`

The condition I use is this:

> RewriteEngine On
>      RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8083/VirtualHostBase/http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/websites/jhom/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]

As note above, when I enter the site URL defined in the server name, I get the default Apache page without a rewrite. When I enter the URL defined in the rewrite into my browser (substituting the server name for localhost) I do get the site! So my assumption is there is something I am missing in the rewrite rule (I tried alternatives with that as well btw) or in getting rewrites to work at all.

If anyone has any good ideas I would greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: You didn't mention it, but how is your Virtual Host Monster set up within Zope?

Comment: There is a VHM at the top level. When I click on the VHM I don't see a mappings tab so I have no clue how to or if I can change the settings. I assume this is because it's an ancient Zope version

Comment: You don't really need to change anything with it, but it needs to be present at the top level for rewrite rules like the one you're describing to work. Your syntax looks generally reasonable although I'd probably use `^/(.*)$` to force match the whole thing. I personally usually use Apache's `ProxyPassMatch` & `ProxyPassReverse` syntax, but rewrite rules with the `P` flag (like you've got) ought to work, too. Look for path mismatches & the like.

Comment: I've tried ProxyPass as well. No go. I actually have two Zope instances, and neither work with Apache and the VHM. One instance is Zope 2.8.x and the VHM has the mappings tab there - so I can connect by doing `http://name.of.site:8082` w/o Apache.The Zope 2.4.4 seems hopeless although I can use view to see a page. That's good enough since the point of bringing these sites up is more to easily extract content for modernizing the sites.

Comment: Where are your virtual hosts within the ZODB? You may have a path mismatch somewhere. I've got access to something very similar to this that works, so I'm guessing that there's something just a little off somewhere.

Comment: I did test the paths in the browser and it worked. I then copied the path (even though it was identical to what was already there) into the Apache conf and it still didnt work. Keep in mind that this was all copied from another physical server. I preserved the exact file structure and path name from the server where it all worked fine. It is quite possible as you say there is some subtle difference I am just not seeing.

Comment: But I am also beginning to suspect that it somehow has to do with the fact of some incompatibility between these Zope's and the much more modern version of Apache I am using (Apache is the one thing for which I didnt use the original old version). As I noted even in the Zope 2.8 I could only get the stuff to work by adding the path to the mapping tab, something I didnt have to do on the original server. The problem is Zope 2.4 doesnt have the mapping tab, so thats not an option for that instance.

Comment: When I was talking paths I meant the specially constructed ones needed to work with Virtual Host Monster. The `VirtualHostBase` and `VirtualHostRoot` components need to be in the proper places relative to the desired paths. The Zope version I'm looking at is much more recent than yours, but I guess I'd be surprised if somehow a newer Apache version broke compatibility with older Zope versions.

Comment: Oh, also, the setup I'm comparing against doesn't use mappings. Normally you shouldn't need them if your Apache configuration is doing its remapping properly. You usually only use VHM mappings if you're working with a system that doesn't support remapping, so maybe the system you copied from has some hidden Apache config issues masked by those mappings.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As I noted, I actually tested the VHM mappings manually on specific pages, so the paths in the Apache config  were correct. Not to mention the identical configuration worked on the older server.  I tried `ProxyPass` & other alternatives I found in earlier Stackoverflow discussions. None worked! I understand re:mappings but that's the only way I could get it to work. I may try NGINX....

Comment: You're welcome, sorry we don't seem to be getting anywhere fast. I still think that the fact that you needed to add the paths in the mapping tab on the old server is indicating that something on that configuration is wrong, and that you're thus copying a broken Apache config (making your observation about the lack of the mapping tab in the old VHM version key).

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Everything on the old server worked 100% fine w/Apache for both Zope instances. It's on the *new* server that the only way I can get it to work is using mappings, an option only available for the 2.8 zope. So the 2.4 zope cant be displayed *on the new server* except through the manager. Apache worked great on the old server. My guess is something in Apache changed-that's the only component here that's new, besides Ubuntu.

Comment: You're right, I did misunderstand. Theoretically the Apache rewrites shouldn't really matter at all, but it's hard to fault your logic. The system I'm looking at is using current Apache with a Zope 2.13.X running on Python 2.7.5 and works fine without mappings. Maybe you could post a little more of the detail of your rewrite config and I could look through and compare?

Comment: You can see it right at the top of this post :)

Comment: BTW I tried changing to ProxyPass as you earlier suggested, triedhard-coding the SERVER_NAME & various other ways rookie suggested in previous SO onthistopic

Comment: Also note the `VHM` is in the root `/` and the site I am trying to map is as in the expression, in a directory `/websites/jhom`

Comment: Yeah, I think I lost track of that in the interim... :)